# Writing a certain generic method

Tags: c#

I have a series of methods to write, but I think there is some commonality (well, I know there is). The method I'd like to see will take two things, an object and... well, I'm not so sure about the second one, but probably a string.

The object should be generic, although it can only be from a set list (in this case, that commonality seems to be that they inherit from both INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged interfaces).

The string should be the name of a property within the generic object. It should be checked to see if that property exists within that object before being put into use (it would be used as a way to compare the objects by that given property).

So I guess the process would be... generic object gets passed into method (along with property name string). A check to see if the object contains the property. If it does, continue and somehow have access to 'object.PropertyName' where 'PropertyName' was the supplied string.

I don't know if it's easy or possible or even wise, but I know that it would save me some time.

Thanks in advance for any advice you might be able to offer with this.

**Edit**: Thanks for the all the replies so far guys. Let me clarify some things:

**Clarification of 'access'**

When I said, "... and somehow have access to 'object.PropertyName'", what I meant was that the method should be able to use that property name as if it were just a property of that object. So, let's say the string passed in was "ClientName", there would be the ability to read (possibly write, although at the moment I don't think so as it's just a check) object.ClientName, if it was determined that existed.

**What I'm trying to do**

I have a WCF service which accesses an SQL database using Linq. The objects I spoke of are entities, generated from the program SQLMetal.exe, so my objects are things like 'Client', 'User' and this sort of thing. I wrote a method which took a List of entities. This method added only those entities which did not exist within the collection (some could have been duplicates). It figured out which ones were duplicates by checking a property within the entity (which corresponds to data in a column of the database). It's that property which I figured might be variable.

Comment: does "access", mean: to read? to write? both? or...? To set context, there's no *convenient* way to do what you ask... you can use reflection, or use you dissect an `Expression`, or you can pass both a `get` and `set` delegate, or you can pass the backing field as `ref` - which option is most desirable (or: least undesirable) depends **hugely** on what you want to do with it. So... what **do** you want to do with it?

Comment: How do you want to access it? Read? Write? Both? - Ha Marc beat me to it.

Comment: If it's not strong typed then, no, you cannot just call `object.ClientName`. You must use reflection to get the PropertyInfo object and use that to find the value of the property for each object, as in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't really want to check if it's a certain type, and if that is so then you don't have to and its actually easier not to check the type. This shows how to check if the property exists and if it is readable and writeable and shows how to use it after it's found:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    PropertyInfo info = GetProperty(sb, "Capacity");
    //To get the value of the property, call GetValue on the PropertyInfo with the object and null parameters:
    info.GetValue(sb, null);
    //To set the value of the property, call SetValue on the PropertyInfo with the object, value, and null parameters:
    info.SetValue(sb, 20, null);
}

private PropertyInfo GetProperty(object obj, string property)
{
    PropertyInfo info = obj.GetType().GetProperty(property);
    if (info != null && info.CanRead && info.CanWrite)
        return info;
    return null;
}
```

I think only indexer properties can take parameters in C#. And I believe if you wrote properties in VB that take parameters and tried to reference that assembly in C# they would show up as methods instead of properties.

You could also write a function like this that would take 2 objects and a string for a property name and return the result of those properties matching:

```
private bool DoObjectsMatch(object obj1, object obj2, string propetyName)
{
    PropertyInfo info1 = obj1.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    PropertyInfo info2 = obj2.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (info1 != null && info1.CanRead && info2 != null && info2.CanRead)
        return info1.GetValue(obj1, null).ToString() == info2.GetValue(obj2, null).ToString();
    return false;
}
```

Comparing the values of the properties might be tricky because it would compare them as objects and who knows how equality will be handled for them. But converting the values to strings should work for you in this case.

If you know the 2 objects are the same type then you can simplify it:

```
private bool DoObjectsMatch(object obj1, object obj2, string propetyName)
{
    PropertyInfo info = obj1.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (info != null && info.CanRead)
        return info.GetValue(obj1, null).ToString() == info.GetValue(obj2, null).ToString();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi there Nick. Thanks for the answer. I'm confused about the differences between the second and third code samples though. Where do info1 and info2 come from in the third one?

Comment: Typo. info1 and info2 both should have just been info. I fixed it. The difference is 3rd one assumes obj1 and obj2 are the same object type so the propertyinfo for 1 would be the same for the other. In the 2nd one they are not assumed to be the same type so it gets the property info for both.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(T object, string propName) 
    where T : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
(
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(propName);

    if(property == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Property doesn't exist", "propName");

    var value = property.GetValue(object, null);
)
```